# Constraint View Inside Content Of Image View Swift

Tags: swift, uiview, uiimageview, constraints

I have an image view that gets a dynamic image, and uses aspect fit to determine the frame of the image itself. I am trying to constraint a view inside of the image view, but when the image dynamically resizes, the view inside of it doesn't also dynamically resize when my constraints are just set to the borders of the image view.

Is there any way to set the constraint to the content size that the image is after it resizes, inside interface builder?

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by dynamic image?

Comment: @Dopapp As in, the size of the image after it resizes, since it is set to aspect fit. The frame of my image view may be 300 x 300 for example, but if I'm passing in an image that is 50 x 100, then the "actual" frame of the image itself may only be 150 x 300

Comment: So you are looking to resize the image view to perfectly contain a scaled image?

Comment: I'm looking to resize the view inside of the image view, to perfectly fit the scaled image, correct

Answer (score 0):

When you set the image view’s frame, pick an initial height or width—not both. Then, get `image.size` and calculate the proportional other dimension. For example:

```
let width = 100
let height = width * image.size.width / image.size.height * 
imageView.frame.size = CGSize(width: width, height: height)
imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
imageView.image = image
```

Now your imageView is exactly the size of your image. You can do the same thing with a fixed height by simply replacing “height” with “width” and vice versa in the code above.

Hope this is what you’re looking for.